# I think there might be a wasp's nest in my garage or in its walls, how can I tell?

Tags: garage, pest-control, pest

I think there might be a wasp's nest in my family's garage or in its walls. However, I don't know for sure. Here are the facts;

- For the past three days in a row (and a few others over the past two weeks), I've opened the garage door in the morning and a wasp flew out of it.
- We generally leave the garage door open throughout the day to keep it cool, but we close it at night.
- I sometimes see a wasp hover around the garage door.
- There are two garbage cans next to the garage.
- I have not seen more than one wasp at a time inside the garage.
- We have a cat (and therefore pet food) in the garage.

**Given this information, how can I be sure of whether or not there is a wasp's nest inside the house or its walls?** Is it possible that a wasp entered through the open door and got trapped overnight multiple times? My family seems to think so but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might have one in there.  In my area at least, there are two common types that build nests around the house, mud daubers and paper wasps.  The good news is that while both sting, neither are particularly aggressive the way hornets are.

Be careful, however, if you are allergic to bee, hornet, or wasp stings!!

I'd follow one around until you see it hitting the nest.  Mud daubers will often make a characteristic high-pitched buzzing sound as they form the mud into their nest.  They can be just about anywhere though.

Paper wasps seem to prefer high spots and corners.

Locate the nest, spray with wasp insecticide, clean up the mess after they leave or die, and then take steps to plug the opening that they are using to get it.

Comment: Best to spray after dark, when all wasps are in the nest. And then get out quickly, just in case you missed a few.

Answer (score 0):

Move the garbage cans away from the garage and see if wasps are still around. Then get a really bright flashlight and go over the entire garage looking in every nook and cranny. If it's in the walls, there will be a hole or crack somewhere. Double check any soffits because that would be a great place for them to get in.

If it is really driving you crazy, get some foggers and set them off in the garage... just make sure your cat's not in the garage.

Comment: Unless you're wanting to get rid of the cat too...

Comment: Good advice @jwh20. _makes a note..._